# Ways of getting Data in mvc EF6 project - advantage and inconvenient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I would like technical advices to get data (read only) in a project mvc using Entity Framework 6 with .Net Framework 4.6. The data have to be displayed in a view.

I have a complex SQL query stored in a string SQLText (using group by , count and based on views stored in SQL server).

Solution 1:
Use a static function GetData returning a DataSet :

```
DataSet GetData(String queryString)

  { 
    // Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;      
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
    try
    {
      // Connect to the database and run the query.
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);        
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
        
      // Fill the DataSet
      adapter.Fill(ds);       
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {    
      // The connection failed. Display an error message.
      Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";   
    }    
    return ds;    
  }
```

Solution 2 :
Use raw SQL Query

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement> (string sql, params object[] parameters);
```

string EmployeeName= ctx.Database.SqlQuery("Select name from Employees where  id=1").FirstOrDefault();

string is the type use in this example, but a more complex type can be used depending on  the columns issued from the query.

First,  I have to declare TElement.

By the way, about this method, is there a way to use SqlQuery without a Type declaration ?

I tried linq query, but my query is so complex I cannot translate it into linq query.

So, my question is :
What are the advantage and inconvenient (performance, aestheticism, etc) of each solution.

Another solution, would be OK for me.

I am waiting your advices .

Answer (score 0):

I rather prefer the second solution because I think it is more aesthetic and simpler.

You just have to write a few line in you view to get your data.

Example (from the site tutorial):

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    //Get student name of string type
    string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentname from Student where studentid=1").FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Once you get your data in your view, just put them into the model...

Any remarks, comments or advices would be welcome.